# is there a function which is activated when the user exits the webform?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, web-development-server

is there a function that is activated when the user exits the webform? 
for example, if I want the user to mark multiple checkboxes and when he exits the page a function will be called to save the information to a database. (consider I can't communicate to the server using js)

Answer (score 0):

If by "exits the page" you mean closes the browser, no, the browser does not communicate any kind of event or postback to the server when the user closes a browser page.

That means you will need a button or control on the page for the user to click when they are ready to save the info. A postback has to be created for that info to get back to the server, and that means some kind of form submit trigger has to happen.